# Get the inner-table's clicked cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable with a custom Cell Editor and a custom Cell Rendered. This is to allow for displaying a table inside the cells.

I need to be able to right click on a inner table cell, then select delete. My problem now is to recognize the inner table's clicked cell. It sometimes works and sometimes doesn't (it either gives -1 as the cell index, or give an incorrect cell index).

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ComplexTable extends JTable {
    private int[] colorsArray = {0xbbbbbb, 0xff0000, 0xb28959, 0x318c23, 0xc200f2, 0xbf0000, 0x735839};
    private Point clickedLocation;
    private JPopupMenu popupMenu;

    MouseAdapter mouseAdapter = new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            clickedLocation = e.getPoint();

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            super.mousePressed(e);
            clickedLocation = e.getPoint();
        }
    };

    public ComplexTable( TableModel tableModel) {
        this.setModel(tableModel);

        this.addMouseListener(mouseAdapter);

        popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
        JMenuItem deleteItem = new JMenuItem("Delete");
        deleteItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int selectedRow = ComplexTable.this.getSelectedRow();
                int selectedColumn = ComplexTable.this.getSelectedColumn();
                JTable table = ComplexTable.this;

                if(selectedRow < 0){
                    return;
                }

                Component c = table.getCellEditor(selectedRow, selectedColumn).
                        getTableCellEditorComponent(table,
                                table.getValueAt(selectedRow, selectedColumn), true, selectedRow, selectedColumn);

                if (c instanceof JScrollPane) {
                    JViewport viewport = ((JScrollPane) c).getViewport();
                    JTable innerTable = (JTable) viewport.getView();

                    int innerTableSelRow = innerTable.rowAtPoint(clickedLocation);
                    int innerTableSelCol = innerTable.columnAtPoint(clickedLocation);

                    System.out.println("inner " + innerTableSelRow + "," + innerTableSelCol);
                }

                System.out.println("outer " + selectedRow + "," + selectedColumn);
            }
        });

        popupMenu.add(deleteItem);

        this.setComponentPopupMenu(popupMenu);

        for (int i = 0; i < tableModel.getRowCount(); i++) {
            this.setRowHeight(i, 55);
        }

        TableCellRenderer outerTableCellRenderer = new TableCellRenderer() {
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
                    JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
                // If what we're displaying isn't an ArrayList of values we return the normal renderer
                if (((ArrayList<String>) value).size() == 1) {
                    return table.getDefaultRenderer(((ArrayList<String>) value).get(0).getClass())
                            .getTableCellRendererComponent(table, ((ArrayList<String>) value).get(0), isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
                } else {
                    final ArrayList<Object> passed = (ArrayList<Object>) value;

                    JTable innerTable = new JTable(new AbstractTableModel() {
                        public int getColumnCount() {
                            return 1;
                        }

                        public int getRowCount() {
                            return passed.size();
                        }

                        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                            return passed.get(rowIndex);
                        }

                        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    });

                    innerTable.setTableHeader(null);

                    InnerTableCellRenderer innerTableCellRenderer = new InnerTableCellRenderer();
                    TableColumnModel columnModel = innerTable.getColumnModel();
                    for (int i = 0; i < columnModel.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                        columnModel.getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(innerTableCellRenderer);
                    }

                    innerTable.addMouseListener(mouseAdapter);

                    return new JScrollPane(innerTable);
                }
            }
        };

        OuterTableCellEditor outerTableCellEditor = new OuterTableCellEditor();

        TableColumnModel tableColumnModel = this.getColumnModel();
        for (int i = 0; i < tableColumnModel.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            tableColumnModel.getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(outerTableCellRenderer);
            tableColumnModel.getColumn(i).setCellEditor(outerTableCellEditor);
        }
    }

    class OuterTableCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {

        Object value = null;

        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
            this.value = value;
            if (((ArrayList<String>) value).size() == 1) {
                JTextField textField = new JTextField(((ArrayList<String>) value).get(0));
                textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                        ArrayList<String> newValue = new ArrayList<>();
                        newValue.add(((JTextField) e.getSource()).getText());
                        OuterTableCellEditor.this.value = newValue;

                        fireEditingStopped();
                    }
                });
                textField.setComponentPopupMenu(popupMenu);
                return textField;

            } else {
                final ArrayList<Object> passed = (ArrayList<Object>) value;
                final JTable innerTable = new JTable();
                innerTable.setTableHeader(null);

                AbstractTableModel innerTableModel = new AbstractTableModel() {
                    public int getColumnCount() {
                        return 1;
                    }

                    public int getRowCount() {
                        return passed.size();
                    }

                    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                        return passed.get(rowIndex);
                    }

                    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
                        return true;
                    }

                    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
                        passed.set(row, value);
                        fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
                    }
                };
                innerTable.setModel(innerTableModel);

                InnerTableCellRenderer innerTableCellRenderer = new InnerTableCellRenderer();
                TableColumnModel columnModel = innerTable.getColumnModel();
                for (int i = 0; i < columnModel.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                    columnModel.getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(innerTableCellRenderer);
                }
                innerTable.setComponentPopupMenu(popupMenu);
                innerTable.addMouseListener(mouseAdapter);
                return new JScrollPane(innerTable);
            }
        }


        @Override
        public Object getCellEditorValue() {
            return this.value;
        }
    }

    class InnerTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean
                isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            c.setBackground(new Color(colorsArray[row]));
            return c;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] columns = {"Name", "E-Mail", "Phone"};

        Object[][] data = new Object[2][columns.length];
        ArrayList<Object> namesList = new ArrayList<>();
        namesList.add("Peter");
        data[0][0] = namesList;
        String[] emails = {"peter@yahoo.com", "strange@name.com"};
        data[0][1] = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(emails));
        String[] phones = {"555 35 25 65", "555 35 24 63", "555 05 55 55", "555 05 55 66"};
        data[0][2] = new ArrayList<Object>(Arrays.asList(phones));
        String[] number = {"12.2"};
        data[1][0] =  new ArrayList<Object>(Arrays.asList(number));
        String[] email = {"Jack@hotmail.com"};
        data[1][1] = new ArrayList<Object>(Arrays.asList(email));
        String[] phones2 = {"555 35 24 33", "555 11 88 88", "332 55 25 34"};
        data[1][2] = new ArrayList<Object>(Arrays.asList(phones2));

        AbstractTableModel outerTableModel = new AbstractTableModel() {
            public String getColumnName(int col) {
                return columns[col];
            }

            public Class getColumnClass(int col) {
                if (getRowCount() < 1) {
                    return null;
                }
                return data[0][col].getClass();
            }

            public int getRowCount() {
                return data.length;
            }

            public int getColumnCount() {
                return columns.length;
            }

            public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
                return data[row][col];
            }

            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
                return true;
            }

            public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
                data[row][col] = value;
                fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
            }
        };

        ComplexTable complexTable = new ComplexTable(outerTableModel);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 700, 400);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(complexTable));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From observation, outer table rely on `JTable.getSelectedRow()` and `JTable.getSelectedColumn()` to obtain the selected cell, while the inner table rely on last clicked location, provided by `MouseAdapter`.

The first problem is, right click would not change table cell selection. Which means if you selected (left-click) [0,0] cell(top-left) and right click at the bottom-right, the outer selection is still [0,0].

The second problem is, the `MouseAdapter` is attached to the outer table and inner table. You need to make sure the event sequence is happening as the way you want. Since clicking on the inner table is also another click event for the outer table. If the inner table click event fire before the outer table, the `clickedLocation` will be overwritten by outer table coordinates, thus its value will be w.r.t outer table. Outer table size around 700*400, and inner table may be 200*80. The x and y for the outer and inner table has different meaning as they are not aligned and vary in size. It is impossible to get the selected inner cell by coordinates capture from outer table.

I modify the project base on your source. Major changes are:

1. For the data model, I keep single data element as a String, not an ArrayList with single String (see `ComplexTableModel.prepareData()`)
2. I didn't add `MouseAdapter` to the table, but add action listener to JPopupMenu (see `TablePopupMenu`)
3. I acquire the table cell selection in `popupMenuWillBecomeVisible()` event.

And this is the result
[image]

ComplexTable.java

```java
public class ComplexTable extends JTable {

    private NestedTableCellRenderer nestedTableRenderer;

    private NestedTableCellEditor nestedTableEditor;

    private Point outerSelection;
    private Point innerSelection;

    public ComplexTable(TableModel tm) {
        super(tm);
        setRowHeight(55);
        setComponentPopupMenu(new TablePopupMenu());

        nestedTableRenderer = new NestedTableCellRenderer(this);
        nestedTableEditor = new NestedTableCellEditor(this);
    }

    @Override
    public TableCellRenderer getCellRenderer(int row, int column) {
        Object data = this.getModel().getValueAt(row, column);
        if (data instanceof List) {
            return nestedTableRenderer;
        } else {
            return super.getCellRenderer(row, column);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public TableCellEditor getCellEditor(int row, int column) {
        Object data = this.getModel().getValueAt(row, column);
        if (data instanceof List) {
            return nestedTableEditor;
        } else {
            return super.getCellEditor(row, column);
        }
    }

    private void printSelection() {
        System.out.println(String.format("outer[%s, %s], inner[%s, %s]", outerSelection.x, outerSelection.y,
                innerSelection.x, innerSelection.y));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ComplexTable complexTable = new ComplexTable(new ComplexTableModel());

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 700, 400);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(complexTable));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class TablePopupMenu extends JPopupMenu implements ActionListener, PopupMenuListener {
        private JMenuItem deleteMenuItem;

        public TablePopupMenu() {
            deleteMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Delete");
            deleteMenuItem.addActionListener(this);
            add(deleteMenuItem);
            addPopupMenuListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            ComplexTable.this.printSelection();
        }

        @Override
        public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
            // update outer selection on context menu shown
            Point mousePoint = ComplexTable.this.getMousePosition();

            int row = ComplexTable.this.rowAtPoint(mousePoint);
            int col = ComplexTable.this.columnAtPoint(mousePoint);

            ComplexTable.this.changeSelection(row, col, false, false);
            outerSelection = new Point(row, col);

            JTable table = (JTable) this.getInvoker();
            if (!(table instanceof ComplexTable)) {
                // inner table is a generic swing table, thus the event fires from inner table
                innerSelection = new Point(table.getSelectedRow(), table.getSelectedColumn());
            } else {
                // clear the selection as -1, -1
                innerSelection = new Point(-1, -1);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void popupMenuCanceled(PopupMenuEvent e) {
        }

    }

}
```

ComplexTableModel.java

```java
public class ComplexTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private String[] columnNames = { "Name", "E-Mail", "Phone" };
    Object[][] rawData = new Object[2][columnNames.length];

    public ComplexTableModel() {
        prepareData();
    }

    private void prepareData() {
        rawData[0][0] = "Peter";
        rawData[0][1] = Arrays.asList("peter@yahoo.com", "strange@name.com");
        rawData[0][2] = Arrays.asList("555 35 25 65", "555 35 24 63", "555 05 55 55", "555 05 55 66");
        rawData[1][0] = "12.2";
        rawData[1][1] = "Jack@hotmail.com";
        rawData[1][2] = Arrays.asList("555 35 24 33", "555 11 88 88", "332 55 25 34");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return columnNames[column];
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return rawData.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return rawData[rowIndex][columnIndex];
    }

}
```

NestedTableCellRenderer.java

```java
public class NestedTableCellRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {
    private JTable masterTable;

    public NestedTableCellRenderer(JTable masterTable) {
        this.masterTable = masterTable;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
            int row, int column) {

        List<?> valueList = (List<?>) value;

        JTable innerTable = new JTable() {
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return true;
            }
        };
        ((DefaultTableModel) innerTable.getModel()).addColumn("", new Vector<Object>(valueList));
        innerTable.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new ColoredInnerTableCellRenderer());
        innerTable.setComponentPopupMenu(masterTable.getComponentPopupMenu());
        innerTable.setTableHeader(null);

        return new JScrollPane(innerTable);
    }

}

class ColoredInnerTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    private int[] colorsArray = { 0xbbbbbb, 0xff0000, 0xb28959, 0x318c23, 0xc200f2, 0xbf0000, 0x735839 };

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
            int row, int column) {

        Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        c.setBackground(new Color(colorsArray[row % colorsArray.length]));

        return c;
    }

}
```

NestedTableCellEditor.java

```java
public class NestedTableCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {

    private JTable masterTable;

    Object value = null;

    public NestedTableCellEditor(JTable masterTable) {
        this.masterTable = masterTable;
    }

    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        this.value = value;

        final List<Object> dataList = (List<Object>) value;
        final JTable innerTable = new JTable();
        innerTable.setTableHeader(null);

        AbstractTableModel innerTableModel = new AbstractTableModel() {
            public int getColumnCount() {
                return 1;
            }

            public int getRowCount() {
                return dataList.size();
            }

            public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return dataList.get(rowIndex);
            }

            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
                return true;
            }

            public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
                dataList.set(row, value);
                fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
            }
        };
        innerTable.setModel(innerTableModel);

        innerTable.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new ColoredInnerTableCellRenderer());

        innerTable.setComponentPopupMenu(masterTable.getComponentPopupMenu());
        return new JScrollPane(innerTable);

    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you notice, I am attaching also the inner table to the MouseAdapter. And even if I remove the attachment from the outer table to the MouseAdapter the code still not working.

Comment: Right, can yes have 2 mouse adapters. Each for outer and inner table? It won't solve the problem right away, but it make us clear on what hinder us to achieve the goal.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but the problem still exists even in the GIF you have shared (notice when you select "peter@yahoo.com" the console prints inner[-1,-1]). This is what was occurring with me, it sometimes works and some others not.

Comment: It is due to I haven't perform a left click to bring the focus to the inner table.

Comment: And this is a problem, the user may right click directly on an inner table and select delete.

Comment: Add to that your code didn't render the complex cells correctly, it shows it as an array, for example: "[peter@yahoo.com, strange@name.com]"

Comment: It shows the inner table as an array? I can't see that in the gif. It render as an colored table isn't it?